# set back down here

Tags: phrase-meaning

Can you explain to me what "set back down here" means?
I've looked up in dictionary and have found that "set back" is meaning "delay", but I'm not completely sure it matches my text.
Also I couldn't find in dictionary meaning of "down here". Does that mean "somewhere where you are situated far away of me"?
The text is:

> Dad tried his transmission again, and Mrs. Coleman came on.
> "This is Bime radio, go ahead."
> "Roger, Bime. We just took off from there, and I've got a low fuel reading."
> "Did you fuel at Sentani?" she said.
> "Roger."
> "Then you should be good to Yawsikor. You think it's an instrument problem?"
> "Hoping."
> "Roger. You want to be safe and **set back down here**?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "set back" can mean to delay, but that's not the meaning here.

In general, to "set" is to place something. Like, "Set the book on the table" means to put the book on the table. Specifically, to "set down" is to put something that you are carrying on a fixed surface. Like someone might say, "You can set that package down on the counter."

"Back", when used as an adverb, means to restore something to a previous condition. For example, "Put the things you stole back" means to return them to the place you stole them from. "Turn the clock back" means to set the clock to a time that has already passed, etc.

So "Set back down" means to put something on a fixed surface that it had previously occupied.

The conversation you quote appears to be about someone flying an airplane whose instruments indicate that he is running out of fuel. A flight controller (or someone) from the airport he just left tells him to "set back down here", that is, to return to the airport he just left and land.

Comment: It might help to note that "to set down", "to touch down" and "to land" are roughly synonymous in avionics jargon.  Mrs. Coleman is asking whether the pilot wants to return (that's the "back") and land (that's the "set .. down") at Bime (that's the "here").

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan Fair enough.